# Ruby method with maximum number of parameters

Tags: ruby, variadic-functions

I have a method, that should accept maximum 2 arguments. Its code is like this:

```
def method (*args)
  if args.length < 3 then
    puts args.collect
  else
    puts "Enter correct number of  arguments"
  end
end
```

Is there more elegant way to specify it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have several alternatives, depending on how much you want the method to be verbose and strict.

```
# force max 2 args
def foo(*args)
  raise ArgumentError, "Too many arguments" if args.length > 2
end

# silently ignore other args
def foo(*args)
  one, two = *args
  # use local vars one and two
end

# let the interpreter do its job
def foo(one, two)
end

# let the interpreter do its job
# with defaults
def foo(one, two = "default")
end
```

Answer (score 12):

if the maximum is two arguments, why use the splat operator like that at all? Just be explicit. (unless there is some other constraint that you haven't told us about.)

```
def foo(arg1, arg2)
  # ...
end
```

Or...

```
def foo(arg1, arg2=some_default)
  # ...
end
```

Or even...

```
def foo(arg1=some_default, arg2=some_other_default)
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Raise an error better. If the arguments are not correct, this is serious problem, which shouldn't pass in your with a humble `puts`.

```
def method (*args)
  raise ArgumentError.new("Enter correct number of  arguments") unless args.length < 3
  puts args.collect
end
```