# How to pass multiple arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, watir

I am new to Ruby and couldn't get any help from answers here, because code level seems pretty advance here:

1. [How do I pass multiple arguments to a ruby method as an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831077/how-do-i-pass-multiple-arguments-to-a-ruby-method-as-an-array)
2. [Ruby method with maximum number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967735/ruby-method-with-maximum-number-of-parameters)
3. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm

I have created a step_definitions like this:

```
Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)" as the name for line item (.*)$/) do |puppy_name, line_item|
  @cart.name_for_line_item line_item
end
```

where method `name_for_line_item`takes only one argument i.e. `line_item`
but in above step_definition I have to verify the `puppy_name` I am passing.

So I tried:

`@cart.name_for_line_item.should include puppy_name line_item` but this is red line of error under the method and

if I try

`@cart.name_for_line_item line_item .should include puppy_name` it give compile time error:

`RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError`

*Source: Cucumber and Cheese by Jeff Morgan*

Comment: try `@cart.name_for_line_item(line_item).should include(puppy_name)`.

Comment: just `include` or `.should include`

Comment: it gave error `.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
  @cart.name_for_line_item include (puppy_name, line_item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use parenthesis :

```
(@cart.name_for_line_item(line_item).should).include? puppy_name
```

Latest version of rspec allow another syntax :

```
expect(@cart.name_for_line_item(line_item)).to include(puppy_name)
```

Link to rspec documentation : https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers

Comment: #first gave `NoMethodError: undefined method include?' for #RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::PositiveOperatorMatcher:0x2e98c90>` but second worked like charm. Such a quick reply.